# List of other apps which can be terminated

Tags: ios, process

I have an app where the requirement is to view all the user-initiated apps, which can be terminated. I tried searching, but didn't find a way to proceed. I am able to get all the processes, including system and user processes,b ut I need to filter only the apps which can be terminated. One way I found could be filtering based on pid, but I am not able to distinguish between pids of user and system processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Apple's SDK this is isn't able and such an application wouldn't get through the approval process of the AppStore. You will need to use a jailbroken iOS device for this kind of job.

Anyway I'd recommend you not to investigate in managing applications manually, since iOS makes a nearly perfect job there already.